# Getting a 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON', for Flask + React

Tags: reactjs, flask

From what I can tell, my React front end is making a call to localhost:3000, which is what it is hosted on. The Flask backend is on localhost:5000, and it works fine. I addded the

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

in package.json, but for some reason it has no effect and still calls to 3000.

My App.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([{}])

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch("/members").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(
      data => {
        setData(data)
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  },[])

  return (
    <div>App</div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and my server.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app =  Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/members")

def members():
    return {"members": ["member1", "member2", "member3"]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Any guidance on how to tackle this is appreciated, first time working with a full stack application and i've seem to hit quite a roadblock. On MacOS.

I tried a few solutions online, but did not really understand them well enough to know if they were implemented correctly.

Comment: This works just fine with a fresh CRA app, and your config is correct. Did you `ctrl+c` and re-`npm start` after adding the `proxy` in package.json? Do you see request logs from the terminal where you're running Flask?

Comment: I just ctrl-c and re-npm started, now getting a: App.js:9     GET http://localhost:3000/members 500 (Internal Server Error) error. No request logs either.

Comment: Just to clarify are you on a recent version of Node? And `curl http://localhost:5000/members` works (obviously it should, there's almost no code there, but just checking)? And the terminal running npm start doesn't report a proxy error?

Comment: Node is recent, just downloaded it. Curl works, and yeah, there is a proxy error: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /members from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Comment: That error means the Flask server probably isn't actually running on localhost:5000, or is otherwise blocked. Anything going on with network settings, a firewall, some security setting, that could be blocking local requests to other ports?

Comment: thanks, this helped. Changed the proxy to http://127.0.0.1:5000, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

`fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/members")`

this should help, change the url in the production